# Convert Openssl explicit ECC public key to named curve public key

Tags: openssl, cryptography

While generating ECC keys using OpenSSL we can specify whether we want explicit public key info or named curve.

Named Curve: `openssl ecparam -name secp256r1 -genkey -noout -out my.key.pem`

Explicit Curve: `openssl ecparam -name secp256r1 -genkey -noout -out my.key.pem -param_enc explicit`

We can extract the public keys by using this command: `openssl ec -in my.key.pem  -pubout -outform pem -out mykey.pub`

For explicit curve keys inside mykey.pub all the curve parameters are also embedded.

Suppose, I have only the public key. I want to know, is there any way to convert the public key with explicit curve info to a public key with named curve or not.
I want to do this because lots of other libraries like bouncycastle, pycrypto does not accept public key with explicit curve parameters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know of such a library. I'm a bit stunned about your remark about Bouncy not accepting these kind of public keys; I'm pretty sure that it does have support for it. I'd easily create a Bouncy Castle based command line (or OpenSSL based command line) to convert back to named curves, but I'd have to program it...

Answer (score 0):

This will convert EC public key that contains explicit EC parameters to EC public key which encodes the named curve:

`openssl ec -in pub.pem -pubin -param_enc named_curve > pub_named.pem`